# form submit in rails not working, possible routing/path error unsure why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-activerecord, rails-routing

I am trying to submit a form in rails that is just a pdf uplaod (using paperclip). There is something wrong with either my form, controller or model and i am not sure which.

this is my form:

```
<%= form_for @yearguide, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
<%= form.file_field :pdf %>

<%= form.submit "Add Event", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

my controller:

```
  class YearController < ApplicationController

    def new
    @yearguide = Year.create(year_params)
end

 def create
if @yearguide = Year.save
  redirect_to '/'
else
    render 'new'
end
 end
```

my model:

```
  class YearlyGuide < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :pdf
   validates_attachment :document, content_type: { content_type: "application/pdf" }
   end
```

my routes:

```
    resources :year
```

I add the file and press upload, but I am being redirected to 'update.html.erb'.
The file doesn;t exist in the db, just an empty record.

When i debug the params on pressing uplaod I get this output

```
    {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"G7ZrXEiip/gsqhDObcfYhTT9kerYZGk+Zl29kWA5jos=", "year"=>{"pdf"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000001029b0340 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/ns/ry6z7jfd6qg6j8xr2q6dw0yc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140609-21455-1eg1sk3>, @original_filename="Artsmill Hebden Bridge Exhibition Programme 2014.pdf", @content_type="application/pdf", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"year[pdf]\"; filename=\"Artsmill Hebden Bridge Exhibition Programme 2014.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Add Event", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"year", "id"=>"9"}
```

=========================
EDIT

OK, so discrepancies with my naming led to the previosu errors, i started again, generating:

```
 rails g model YearlyGuide pdf:attachment start:datetime end:datetime

 rails g controller YearlyGuide new index show
```

now in my routes i have added

```
   resources :yearly_guides
```

when i visit

```
   /yearly_guides/new
```

I get this error

```
 uninitialized constant YearlyGuidesController
```

I am really at a loss as to what I am doing wrong, I have done this before and never had these issues.

@iceman, thanks for your help and patience thus far.

Comment: `@yearguide` in `create` doesn't exist. The one you created in `new` is long gone.

Comment: ammended, still doesn't work

Comment: Are you trying to save a `Year` or a `YearlyGuide`?

Comment: u should add url, and http method too in the form_for,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller is not doing what it's supposed to do. This is the bare bones basic scheme of creating a new object in Rails.

```
class YearsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @yearguide = Year.new
  end

  def create
    @yearguide = Year.create(year_params)
    if @yearguide.save
      redirect_to '/' # I would consider redirect_to @yearguide to show the newly created object
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT:

You have to update your routes.rb to

```
resources :years
```

Comment: i still get this error though,

undefined method `years_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000010c049e28>:0x0000010b450360>

Comment: There is some disreptancy in your naming, you have `YearController` but `YearlyGuide` and then `@yearguide` and `resources :year`

Comment: @rico_mac You have to update your routes.rb to

resources :years

Comment: see edit, i have started again, still having similar routing problems

Comment: @rico_mac resources :yearly_guides has to match the controller name, the name must be YearlyGuidesController. Have you taken a look at the Rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Yeah I was spun out by the pluralise method in rails.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating the yearguide object, rails infer that you have to do put/patch request, so request is going to update since rails getting id.

You have two options. 
  1) Change new method of controller like below

```
class YearController < ApplicationController

 def new
   @yearguide = Year.new
 end
end
```

2) Override the method parameter by passing method params as 'post' inside your form tag

Comment: changed to this,  <%= form_for @yearguide, :html => {  :method=>"post" } do |form| %>
I get error 'undefined method `years_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000010c5c1ae0>:0x0000010c5c0bb8>
"